# CSS: Placing <divs> on a responsively resized image

Tags: css

I have an image. It scales in size responsively, while maintaining its aspect ratio. 
On top of that image a couple of smaller images are laid out (navigation links).
Those smaller images *must* scale with the main-image *and* be at the (relative) same spot at all times.

**UPDATE:**

I made a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/v9V5p/

Bart Simpson is the image. It should always stay within the confines of the the dark-blue container. A light-blue navigation-link is overlaid, it should always cover Bart's face.

This will work in WebKit-browsers, in FF or Opera Bart will be too big. If you use one of these browsers: Bart should be centered in a dark-blue container which is only 75% of the preview-window-height.

---

The first idea was this:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="navigation-link"></div>
    <div class="navigation-link"></div>
    <div class="navigation-link"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.image-container {
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: whatever px;
    background: url(my image) no-repeat bottom center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Easy.
The problem is `image-container` can grow larger than the image in either `height` or `width` and I don't know of a way in CSS to find out which it is, thus I have no way to consistently place/scale the `navigation-link`s in respect to their parent div.

My solution was:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img class="image" src="my image" />
        <div class="navigation-link"></div>
        <div class="navigation-link"></div>
        <div class="navigation-link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.image-container {
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: whatever px;
}
.image-wrapper {
    display: inline-block; // shrink-to-fit
}
.image {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The `img` scales while keeping its aspect ratio and `image-wrapper` shrinks to fit around it, thereby giving the `navigation-links` something to hook into.

That works beautifully ... in WebKit-browsers.

Firefox and Opera set `max-height` and `max-width` to `auto` if the parent element doesn't have `height` and `width` set. I've been told that's according to W3C specs.

Is there any way I can do what I want in CSS? I don't want to turn to JavaScript for layouting, if I don't have to.

Comment: why not just set `height:auto;` and `width:auto;`?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea setting .image-wrapper height and width to auto doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the .image class to this:

```
.image {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

so the image resizes to fit based on its parents width and height

note: the image will remain proportional with the above

**UPDATE:**

what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/v9V5p/35/

adding a **height:100%;** to the **.wrapper class**

```
.wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #555;

   height:100%; /* added this */
}
```

also adding this to the html, body:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't even work in WebKit browsers :o) The problem is that the parent of .image CANNOT have a height or width (in my solution), as it is meant to shrink-to-fit

Comment: do you have an example of this in jsfiddle or codepen to better help you?

Comment: Good idea, I just did.

Comment: The problem now is that the .wrapper doesn't resize anymore, so the link start to lose its aspect ratio. That's definitely an improvement of sorts, but it's giving me new problems, e.g. the clickable area grows past the image representing the link. But I appreciate the effort!

Comment: i did notice that the .image-container had position:absolute; which takes the element out of the document flow.. usually when you an element using position absolute you would have one of its parents it is relative to have position:relative; .. i think Firefox doesnt apply the resize because of this position absolute.. unless im not seeing all the code from teh code on your local

Comment: I just set the parent of the image-container to position: relative and it didn't change anything.